# How to get the value of H1 tag and test it using Jest and RTL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my component if it displays the right value in my h1.

Below is my component that will be tested.

```
  const Title = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 aria-label='Title of the project'>MY RTL PROJECT</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Title;
```

and here is my test file that tries to check if my component displays "MY RTL PROJECT".

```
import { render, } from '@testing-library/react';
import Title from '../Title';


    describe('Checks the title component', () => {
    
        it('checks the value of the Title component', () => {
            const { getByText } = render(<Title />);
            const titleValue = getByText('MY RTL PROJECT')
            expect(titleValue).toBe('MY RTL PROJECT')
        })
    })
```

and here is the error:   **"messageParent" can only be used inside a worker**

```
  ● Checks the title component › checks the value of the Title component

expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "MY RTL PROJECT"
Received: <h1 aria-label="Title of the project">MY RTL PROJECT</h1>
```

Comment: Show the full error stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```js
const titleValue = getByText('MY RTL PROJECT')
```

...is returning you an element, not the text the element contains.  So instead of this line:

```js
expect(titleValue).toBe('MY RTL PROJECT')
```

...you might want to use [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) `toHaveTextContent()`:

```js
expect(titleValue).toHaveTextContent('MY RTL PROJECT')
```

That said-- you are getting an element by text, then verifying it contains the text you just used to query it, so that test might not be of very high value.  It might make more sense to just verify that it is there:

```js
const titleValue = getByText('MY RTL PROJECT')
expect(titleValue).toBeInTheDocument();
```

...which is also from [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom).

Also, although I cannot say with certainty, the usage of `aria-label` to apply text to your heading that is different than the text the heading contains seems dubious to me-- you might want to verify that that doesn't represent an accessibility anti-pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The question is pretty old, but I figured that for anyone coming here a cleaner solution would be:

```js
screen.getByRole('heading', {level: 1})
```

The level property can go 1 to 6 and is needed to specify the level of heading you're aiming to retrieve. So level 1 would be h1, level 2 h2 and so on

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `getByRole()` or `queryByRole()`, that way you don't even have to specify the text,...

```js
    const titleValue = screen.getByRole('heading');
    expect(titleValue).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(titleValue).toHaveTextContent(/my rtl project/i);
```

... although you can specify text, if you want to:

```js
    const titleValue = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /my rtl/i });
```

More information about `*ByRole` functions:
https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/

Answer (score 0):

```
let wrapper = container.querySelector('h1');

expect(wrapper?.textContent).toEqual('MY RTL PROJECT');
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).